# Getting a state of from a component and show it as a value attribute inside a div?

Tags: reactjs, attributes, export, react-props

**In functional components**
I want to share a function I have with a few components, to prevent duplicated code. All I need is the `state` that the function changes.

Is it possible to get the `state` from **UpdateNum.jsx** component to other components (as I showed in the code) ?
Or, is it possible to pass this function to other components so I can use it multiple times ? ( also to send props to the function)

```js
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    export default function UpdateNum(change) {
      const [numberCon , setNumber ] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {    
          setNumber(numberCon + 1)
      },[change])

      return numberCon;

    }
```

I want to get the `numberCon` state in **Shop.jsx** inside the `value={}` attribute

```js
import UpdateNum from './functions/UpdateNum';

  <div className='cart-icon' value={''}>
            <FaShoppingCart size={40} />
          </div>
```

And also at **Items.jsx** as I do -

```js
import UpdateNum from './functions/UpdateNum';

 return (
    <div >
      <h1 style={{ marginLeft: '30px' }}>
         <UpdateNum/> - Items  <br />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UpdateNum function should return a component , if you want that function to return the actual state value , then you need to make it as a custom hook.

1. prefix the function name with `use` so that react knows that it's a custom hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function useNumberCon() {
  const [numberCon , setNumber ] = useState(0);

    function riseNum() {   //Some function to calculate a number
      setNumber(numberCon + 1)
  }

  return { numberCon, riseNum};
}
```

2. Now in the component where you want to consume this `numberCon` and `riseNum` ( Shop.jsx and Items.jsx )  you can do this

```
// In Shop.jsx
const { numberCon, riseNum } = useNumberCon();

 ......
 ......

 <div className='cart-icon' value={numberCon}>
       <FaShoppingCart size={40} />
 </div>
```

3. If your `<Shop />` and the `<Items />` are sibling to each other then you need to add the custom hook call ( step #2 ) in the parent component which wraps them .

Reference:

[Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

[Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the latest code . Your current code snippet looks confusing .

Comment: Ok I edited the code, before that I thought to use `useEffect` inside the other components instead in `NumberCon` , but that cause an error - `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. `

Comment: @Elassoa you haven't made the changes correctly . You need to replace the `UpdateNum` with the step #1 in my answer . You need a custom hook .

Comment: `useNumberCon ()` another error - `React component names must start with an uppercase letter`. must be `UseNumberCon()` than.

Comment: when a function start with the name `use` its a hook , its not a component . So you can't do this `<UseNumberCon />` in your Items.jsx file .

Comment: Ok and I changed `useNumberCon()` to be a `useMemo` Hook and its all good, thank you so much! now I can even send parameter to this function.

Comment: I didn't understand this part  in your answer - `If your <Shop /> and the <Items /> are sibling to each other then you need to add the custom hook call ( step #2 ) in the parent component which wraps them`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236002/discussion-between-shyam-and-elassoa).

Comment: Just fix please `riseNum()`,  because how will it run and do `useState` on `numberCon `?

Answer (score 0):

1)Isolate your required function and return in new file.

```
export const updateNum = (reciveParam) => {
   
        // do your calculation with reciveParam
        
        return value
     }
```

2)Import the function in required component

```
import updateNum from './util/updateNum';

const returnValue = updateNum(passParams);
```

3)Access here

```
<div className='cart-icon' value={returnValue}>
   <FaShoppingCart size={40} />
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does an error - `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Comment: Can u plz tell me what's wrong in that, but it's working fine to me.

Comment: @MuraliKollati The error in his first comment look.

Comment: @ ExtraSun  i have updated my plz have a look

Answer (score -1):

If all the components share the same parent, you could pass the function as a prop: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component

If they share different parents, or you dont want the hassle of passing the function around, you could make your own hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook